# How i can insert an element in between in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to insert p tag in between other p tag in this example there only 3 p tag are there in my program there can be more so help me out.

**This is Html structure **

```html
  <div id="container">
       <p>P1</p>
       <p>p2</p>
       <p>p3</p>
    </div>
```

i want to insert a p tag in between using javascript . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert elements through many different ways, but the most flexible is [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
and [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```js
const secondP = document.querySelector("#container p:nth-child(2)");

const html = `<p>newly added p</p>`;

// add before the second p
secondP.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html);

// add after the second p
secondP.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", html);
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <p>P1</p>
   <p>p2</p>
   <p>p3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your simplified question, a simpified answer:

```
const p = document.querySelector("#container p:nth-of-type(1)");

p.innerHTML += "<p>new p tag</P>";
```

Where as nth-of-type(1) selects the first p tag.

However, this question has been answered many times here, so please next time take some time to do some research.

Comment: this will work for 3 elements what i have 5 p tag and i want to insert after 3rd ?

Comment: Sorry, but if you want dynamic code then don't tell us where you want what but what algorithm you use to define where it has to be implemented .......

Comment: @PankajJaiswal i did and it's still unclear to me if you want to insert a p tag inside another p tag, or after an existing p tag and by your previous p tag how do I know that if you have now 10 p tags which one to choose from them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a easy hack to do this in javscript:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<p>p4</p>";
```

However, you should be doing it by [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```
tempP = document.createElement('p');
tempP.innerText = "p4";
document.getElementById("container").insertAdjacentElement('afterend',tempP);
```